# Athena array aggregate and filter multiple columns on condition

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I have data as shown below.

| uuid | movie | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | movie1 | {title=rental, label=GA, price=50, feetype=rental, hidden=false} |
| 1 | movie1 | {title=tax, label=GA, price=25, feetype=service-fees, hidden=true} |
| 1 | movie1 | {title=rental, label=GA, price=50, feetype=rental, hidden=false} |
| 1 | movie1 | {title=tax, label=GA, price=25, feetype=service-fees, hidden=true} |
| 2 | movie3 | {title=rental, label=VIP, price=100, feetype=rental, hidden=false} |
| 2 | movie3 | {title=tax, label=VIP, price=25, feetype=service-fees, hidden=true} |
| 2 | movie3 | {title=promo, label=VIP, price=10, feetype=discount, hidden=false} |

and, this is how i want the result to be like.

| uuid | total_fee | total_discount | discount_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 150 | 0 | NA |
| 2 | 125 | 10 | promo |

I tried using

```
SELECT uuid
   , sum("fee"."price") "total_fee"   
   , array_agg(distinct("fee"."feetype")) "fee_type"
   , array_agg(distinct("fee"."title")) "fee_name"
```

This gives the result as shown below,

| uuid | total_fee | fee_type | fee_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | [rental] | [rental] |
| 1 | 50 | [service-fees] | [tax] |
| 2 | 100 | [rental] | [rental] |
| 2 | 25 | [service-fees] | [tax] |
| 2 | 10 | [discount] | [promo] |

Now how do I aggregate on `total_fee` and filter `fee_name` based on `fee_type`?

I tried using

```
, CASE WHEN regexp_like(array_join(fee_type, ','), 'discount') THEN sum("fee") ELSE 0  END "discount"
```

but that resulted in

```
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 207:6: '(CASE WHEN "regexp_like"("array_join"(fee_type, ','), 'discount') THEN "sum"("fee") ELSE 0 END)' must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```sql
SELECT
  uuid,
  SUM(fee.price) AS total_fee,
  SUM(fee.price) FILTER (WHERE fee.feetype = 'discount') AS total_discount,
  ARBITRARY(fee.title) FILTER (WHERE fee.feetype = 'discount') AS discount_type
FROM …
GROUP BY uuid
```

(I'm assuming the `data` column in your example is the same as the `fee` column in your query).

Aggregate functions support a `FILTER` clause that selects the rows to include into the aggregation. This can also be achieved by e.g. `SUM(IF(fee.feetype = 'discount', fee.price, 0))`, which is more compact but not as elegant.

The `ARBITRARY` aggregate function picks an arbitrary value from the group. I don't know if that's appropriate in your case, but I assume that there will only be one discount row per group. If there are more than one you might want to use `ARRAY_AGG` with the `DISTINCT` clause (e.g. `ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT fee.title)` to get the all).